# Divide Array list into 3 column but it not aligned properly in HTML CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Array of Object, I have to divide a list into 3 rows that contain Line, which separate two column, so, I have write the following code:-

```
HTML
let Arr = [
  { num: 'jkjjk' },
  { num: 'jkjjk' },
  { num: 'jkjjkkj dshdjsh jhsjhsdj' },
  { num: 'jkjjkkj dshdjsh jhsjhsdj' },
  { num: 'jkjjkkj  ' },
  { num: 'jkjjkkj  jhsjhsdj' }
];

{Arr.map((element) => (
  <ul className={divide}>
   <li>{element.num}</li>
  </ul>
)}

<div>

CSS

.divide {
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  column-count: 3;
  column-gap: 40px;
  column-rule: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

It's works for me but the list of element are not aligned properly, **In a row, first column element are on top & the rest of the columns element are on middle or bottom of the row,
so, I want to align all the Element in the Column on the top,**

Note:- Alignment mismatch may be due to element String have too much length, thats why Its create problem,

Sugget me how to solve this

Comment: Add some extra code so that your problem can be reproduced . Like `html` and more `css`

Comment: You have multiple problems in your code. 1. Don't use key in the return element from the map function, 2. Using divide as argument instead of wrapping it with quotes

Comment: Yeah, and I'd like to notice that there's not HTML, it's JSX + JavaScript.
Provide extra code.

Comment: @RazLuvaton Just check again I put circular bracket on it, so it automatically returns

Comment: Use the snippets so we can test it

Comment: See [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) for what I meant about keys

Comment: @RazLuvaton do dry run, its obvious

Comment: @RazLuvaton I have done all these thing in my code, my concern is to divide "ul or li" list into 3 column & align all the rows in a column at same level

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237490/discussion-between-sagar-and-raz-luvaton).

Comment: 'column-count' is related to one container, but you have <ul> with <li>s. Try changing <ul> to div.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<ul className="divide">
  {Arr.map((element) => (
    <li>{element.num}</li>
  )}
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.divide li {
  word-break: break-all;
}
```